# How to enable permission to connect in Windows remote desktop?

Tags: remote-desktop

I enabled remote desktop under Windows 7 Ultimate. When I am at work, I connected successfully to my PC via internet. But when my son wants to play a game on my PC; I disconnected and I saw a message which says: `Another user connected`.

I see in a workstation that when a session wants to connect, a message appears and says:

> "Another user is currently logged on to this computer. If you continue, this user has to disconnect from this computer. Do you want to continue?"

Then a message appears to connected session and shows `Allow`/`Disallow` dialog on whether to let it connect. **I want to enable this feature** to show this dialog. How do I do this?